# How to judge whether a list is a sub sequence of another with java8 stream?

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

For example, I have a long list `[1, 2, 3, ..., 10]`, and a short one `[1, 3, 6]`, then I can tell that the short one is the subsequence of another. On the other hand, the list `[1 6 3]` is not because it against the order constraint.

Below is my java7 style code for this question:

```
List<Integer> sequence = Arrays.asList(1, 3, 6);
List<Integer> global = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
Iterator<Integer> iterGlobal = global.iterator();
boolean allMatch = true;
for(Integer itemSequence: sequence) {
    boolean match = false;
    while(iterGlobal.hasNext()) {
        if(itemSequence.equals(iterGlobal.next())) {
            match = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!match) {
        allMatch = false;
        break;
    }
}
System.out.println(allMatch); //=> true
```

And my wish is to find a java8 stream style to achieve the same result.

Comment: What if the input is `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3`, then `1, 3, 6` and `1, 6, 3` might be valid?

Comment: I guess the answer is yes.

Comment: @Flown: yes, both are valid.

Answer (score 6):

Real functional solutions, i.e. not incorporating mutable state, are hard to find. This is best illustrated by the fact that all answer so far incorporate mutable state.

Further, there is no `List.indexOf(T object, int startIndex)` operation. To illustrate, how useful it would be, let define it via helper method:

```
public static int indexOf(List<?> list, int startIndex, Object o) {
    if(startIndex!=0) list=list.subList(startIndex, list.size());
    int ix=list.indexOf(o);
    return ix<0? -1: ix+startIndex;
}
```

<sup>It would be easy to find an alternative implementation without a temporary object, if that’s a concern</sup>

Now, a simple solution using mutable state would be:

```
boolean allMatch = sequence.stream().allMatch(new Predicate<Integer>() {
    int index = 0;
    public boolean test(Integer t) {
        return (index = indexOf(global, index, t)) >=0;
    }
});
```

A functional solution without mutable state requires a value type holding two positions within the two lists. When we use an `int[2]` array for that, the solution would be:

```
boolean allMatch = Stream.iterate(
        new int[]{ 0, global.indexOf(sequence.get(0)) },
        a -> new int[] { a[0]+1, indexOf(global, a[1], sequence.get(a[0]+1)) }
    )
    .limit(sequence.size())
    .allMatch(a -> a[1]>=0);
```

Comment: this is nice. I hope you don't mind me taking your idea and using it a little different because of jdk-9 possibility to iterate over a Stream like you would an Iterator with `hasNext` and `next`.

Answer (score 5):

I am the questioner and I answer my question firstly just for mark:

```
List<Integer> sequence = Arrays.asList(1, 3, 6);
List<Integer> global = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);

Iterator<Integer> iter = global.iterator();
boolean subSequence = sequence.stream().allMatch(itemSequence -> {
    return Stream.generate(iter::next)
            .anyMatch(itemGlobal -> itemSequence.equals(itemGlobal));
});
System.out.println(subSequence);
```

It work well for sequence list [1, 3, 6], while for sequence [1, 6, 3] throwing a error java.util.NoSuchElementException. This is not what I finally want to reach.

Comment: Hmmm if this is not what you want to achieve, then you shouldn't have posted it as an answer, since it can confuse future readers looking for an actual solution for this problem. It would've been better to include it as an example within your question.

Answer (score 3):

A variant of @Eugene's variant of @Run's answer would involve calling Iterable::spliterator on the global List<> value, then apply the result to StreamSupport::stream:

```
final Spliterator<Integer> spliterator = global.spliterator();

final boolean subSequence = sequence.stream().allMatch(
  itemSequence -> StreamSupport.stream(
    spliterator,
    false
  ).anyMatch(itemSequence::equals)
);

System.out.println(subSequence);
```

Comment: If global = [1,6,3], subSequence = false, and if global = [1,3,6], subSequence is true, following @Run's order constraint. Note that List::spliterator reports Spliterator.SIZED and Spliterator.ORDERED, as in the actual List interface default method.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you got really close to the solution (I did not even think about a `Iterator` like this, so a plus one to you). The problem is that **`Stream.generate`** is an infinite stream.

I've changed your code just a bit.

```
    Iterator<Integer> iter = global.iterator();

    boolean subSequence = sequence.stream().allMatch(itemSequence -> {
        return StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(iter, Spliterator.ORDERED), false)
                .anyMatch(itemGlobal -> itemSequence.equals(itemGlobal));
    });
    System.out.println(subSequence);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll add another option after seeing Holger answer; but this will only work with jdk-9 [Stream.iterate](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#iterate-T-java.util.function.Predicate-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-).

I've defined a helper method in the same way, a tiny bit different:

```
private static int fits(List<Integer> global, int elementIndex, int element) {
    return global.indexOf(element) >= elementIndex ? global.indexOf(element) : -1;
}
```

And then just use an `int[2]`:

```
boolean allMatch = Stream.iterate(new int[] { 0, 0 },
            array -> array[0] < sequence.size() && array[1] >= 0,
            array -> new int[] { array[0] + 1, fits(global, array[1], sequence.get(a[0])) })
            .allMatch(array -> array[0] >= array[1]);
```

**EDIT**
Holger is right, this will only work for non-duplicates.

I can write it for duplicates also, but then is suffers from the point that `fits` needs to be called twice now.

```
 boolean allMatch = Stream.iterate(new int[] { 0, 0 },
            a -> {
                return a[0] == sequence.size() ? false : fits(global, sequence.get(a[0])) >= a[1];
            },
            a -> {
                int nextFits = fits(global, sequence.get(a[0]));
                return new int[] { a[0] + 1, nextFits > a[1] ? nextFits + 1 : -1 };
            })
            .count() == sequence.size();
```

Comment: The problem with your `fits` approach is that it doesn’t produce the same result when the list has duplicates. Besides that, starting the search at the beginning each time and even doing it twice can be much more costly than the constant costs of creating a lightweight sublist instance.

Comment: Note that `expression? false: condition` is the same as `!expression && condition`. In other words, instead of `a[0]==sequence.size()? false: fits(global, sequence.get(a[0]))>=a[1]`, you can write `a[0]!=sequence.size() && fits(global, sequence.get(a[0]))>=a[1]`